# adding view on top of googlemap android

Tags: android, view

I want to have 2 views. My first one will be a GoogleMap and then in the four corners I want to add some graphics. I want when the users moves the map the images to stay in the four corners. I coouldn't find any tutorials on that and I do not know where to start searching so if you have any links or any proposal on what to do, inform me and I will come back with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extend the MapView class and override the dispatchDraw() method.

It gives you a canvas and you can draw on it as you please. Afterwards just send it to super() and you have what you want.

Comment: i have thought about that, but I do not want the onDrwa to be in locations, I want to be in the corners of the map, even if i move it. Guess it is possible though, right?

Answer (score 0):

Propably you could use an overlay class. You can find many tutorials on overlay with Google. And just position the images like you want.